# Comparar 2 listas de millones de valores en java

Tags: java, arraylist, hilos

Tengo 2 listas cada una con mas de 4 millones de valores(distintos tamaños), se necesita comparar ambas listas y obtener una lista que tenga los valores iguales, sin embargo demora mucho tiempo.
¿Qué alternativas puedo optar? ¿hilos?
Las listas no están ordenadas, no son del mismo tamaño pero si grandes, son string.

```
lista1 = {id4, id8,id2, id1,....} 
lista2 = {zzzzzz_id8, bbbb_id5, ccc_id7, fffffffff_id2,....}
```

```
    private static List<String> compara(List<String> lista1, List<String> lista2) {
    List<String> iguales= new ArrayList<>();
    lista1.stream().forEach(
            (a) -> {
                lista2.stream()
                        .filter(b -> b.contains(a))
                        .forEach(iguales::add);
            }
    );
    return iguales;
}
```

Comment: Esas listas son ordenadas? 
disponen de una misma cantidad de registros?

Comment: No son ordenadas y no tienen el mismo tamaño.

Comment: Las listas son de Strings o son de Objetos??. Como mencionaron en la respuesta hay dos `foreach` anidados lo que puede aumentar la complejidad, ahora si toma una de las listas y la ordena y posterior a esto realiza una busqueda binaria de cada elemento de la no ordenada en la ordenada, de esta forma la complejidad disminuye ya que se haria un ordenamiento `o(nlogn)` (quicksort) y posterior una busqueda binaria que sería `o(logn)`. suena muy aparatoso pero puede funcionar.

Comment: Qué probabilidad hay de que los elementos de la lista 2 tengan uno correspondiente en la lista 1?

Answer (score 3):

veo que usas dos foreach entonces quizá eso este afectando el rendimiento. Ya que usas Java 8 podrías usar retainAll

El método retainAll de ArrayList se usa para eliminar todos los elementos de la lista de la matriz que no están contenidos en la colección especificada o retiene todos los elementos coincidentes en la instancia actual de ArrayList que coinciden con todos los elementos de la lista de Colección pasados ​​como parámetro al método.

```
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("milan","dingo", "elpha", "hafil", "meat", "iga", "neeta.peeta"));
        List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("hafil", "iga", "binga", "mike", "dingo"));

        listOne.retainAll( listTwo );
        System.out.println( listOne );
```

OutPut

```
[dingo, hafil, iga]
```

Comment: Si, no habría problema en aplicar ese método. Veo que podria mejorar el rendimiento ya que no ejcuta dos ciclos for

Comment: Hola, detallo como son mas o menos las listas:   lista1={id4, id8,id2, id1....} lista2={zzzzzz_id8, bbbb_id5, ccc_id7, fffffffff_id2....} al ser distintas hago un contains para comparar solo por id. ¿No hay inconveniente con el retainAll? ¿Es óptimo al ser de gran tamaño las listas?

Comment: Si, es optimo. Puedes probar esa forma a ver si te funciona ya que no creo que podramos reproducir un ejemplo de ese tamaño.

Comment: Hice el cambio según me indicaste pero no encontró resultados a pesar de que si existen, entiendo que se debe a que no son iguales las listas.

Comment: @EdmunDantes la solución de @Luisa no te funciona como tampoco funciona tu código (basado en los ejemplos del contenido que pones como comentario) ya que el `retainAll()` usa internamente el `contains()` y este a su vez compara los objetos usando el método `equals()`. Creo que debías haber incluído el contenido de ejemplo en tu pregunta.

Comment: @EdmunDantes Si pides ayuda, es importante que describas BIEN tu problema para hacer fácil que se te de ayuda. Si dejas detalles importantes (como que por ejemplo los elementos de la lista no son iguales, o qué significa realmente "comparar"), pues la gente se va a cansar de ir dándote soluciones solo para que tu respondas "es que esto no resuelve mi problema porque mi problema es otro que no te había dicho."

Comment: @EdmunDantes Si haces que sea complicado ayudarte, pues la gente no te ayudará.

Comment: @SJuan76 tienes razón con el tema de los detalles, sin embargo, si lo indique en un comentario, las listas tiene el siguiente formato: ` lista1={id4, id8,id2, id1,....} lista2={zzzzzz_id8, bbbb_id5, ccc_id7, fffffffff_id2,....}.`  Con el código que puse en la pregunta inicial si funciona pero demora mucho tiempo. Lo que hago es recorrer ambas listas y comparar, ` if( zzzzzz_id8.contanis(id8) ) ` , si es correcto lo agrega a la lista iguales. ¿Que otro detalle puedo alcanzar? ¿Porque no me funcionaría con el `retainAll()`?

Comment: 'private static List<String> compara(List<String> lista1, List<String> lista2) {
    List<String> iguales= new ArrayList<>(lista2);
    iguales.retainAll(lista1);
    return iguales;
} '
Ese fue el código que utilice según el cambio de @Luisa

Comment: @EdmunDantes Por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir los detalles. Tú código funciona porque *"zzzzzz_id8".contains("id8")* devuelve *true*, pero *retains* compara los dos String usando *equals* (y *"zzzzzz_id8".equals("id8")* devuelve *false*). Una solución puede ser crear una tercera lista, donde extraes el "id" de cada elemento (si encuentras "zzzz_id8" en la nueva lista guardas "id8") y usar la respuesta de Luisa con la nueva lista.

Answer (score 0):

Si se permite copiar las listas (que sería espacio adicional O(n)) entonces puedes resolverlo muy simplemente asi:

```
Set<String> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(lista1);
set1.retainAll(lista2);
lista1 = new ArrayList<>(set1);
```

Tiempo de ejecución es O(n).
Más rápido que ordenar. Pero utiliza O(n) espacio adicional.