# ¿Como comparar dos ArrayList?

Tags: java

tengo que crear un metodo que me compare dos arrayList

**Entrada de muestra 1:**

alice: 17 28 30

bob: 99 16 8

**Salida de muestra 1:**

[2,1]

**Explicación 1**

Comparando el 0th  elementos, 17 < 99 entonces Bob recibe un punto.
Comparando el 1th y  elementos, 28 > 16 y  30 > 8 por lo que Alice recibe dos puntos.
La matriz de retorno es [2,1]

```
     public List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
            ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            int v1=0, v2=0;
            for(int i = 0; i< a.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j< b.size();j++){
                    if(a.get(i) > b.get(j)){
                      // operacion
                    }if(a.get(i) == b.get(j)){
                       //operacion
                    
                    }if(a.get(i) < b.get(j)){
                      //operacion
                    }
                }
            }
            
            lista.add(v1);
            lista.add(v2);
            return lista;
                 
        }
```

Pero lo que no se es como hacer que el elemento de alice cumple dos condiciones se sumen y me retorne un 2 o viceversa no se si me hice entender xd , alguna idea de como resolver esta pequeña duda, gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar 2 listas de millones de valores en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364249/comparar-2-listas-de-millones-de-valores-en-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta anidar los `for`. Ambas listas tienen el mismo tamaño y  pueden iterarse al mismo tiempo con un solo `for` comparando `a.get(i)` con `b.get(i)`.

```
public List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
            ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                
                // sacar la diferencia de a - b 
                int diferencia = a.get(i) - b.get(i);
                // si la diferencia es negativa es porque b es mayor
                if(diferencia < 0) v2++;
                // si la diferencia es positiva es porque a es mayor
                if(diferencia > 0) v1++;
                
            }
    
            lista.add(v1);
            lista.add(v2);
            return lista;
    
        }
```